# Airflow health checks fails when too many tasks are running?

Tags: airflow

I have a single container Airflow setup running on Marathon, using the LocalExecutor. I have a health check running that pings the `/health` endpoint on the Airflow webserver. It currently has 5 cpus allocated to it and the webserver is running 4 Gunicorn. Last night I had about 25 tasks running concurrently. This caused the health check to fail w/o a helpful error message. The container just received a SIGTERM. I was wondering if anyone could suggest a likely culprit for what caused the health check to fail? Was it CPU contention? Did I not create enough gunicorn workers so that they could respond to the health check request? I have a few ideas, but I'm not certain as to the cause.

Here's the health check configuration in Marathon:

```
[
  {
    "gracePeriodSeconds": 300,
    "intervalSeconds": 60,
    "timeoutSeconds": 20,
    "maxConsecutiveFailures": 3,
    "portIndex": 0,
    "path": "/admin/",
    "protocol": "HTTP",
    "ignoreHttp1xx": false
  }
]
```

Comment: What is the configuration for your health check re: interval, retries, timeout, etc?

Comment: @joebeeson just added it to the post

Answer (score 1):

Yep I have seen similar issues before, would it be possible to migrate away from LocalExecutor and single node Airflow services.

If not, it's a case of vertically scaling your instance, to be able to handle the web request during times of heavy compute requirement from Tasks // Scheduler.

Comment: I can probably do the migration at some point, but I was hoping to just vertically scale in the near term. But I'm trying to figure out what exactly I need to vertically scale. I guess I'm trying to figure out do I need to increase # cpus, # Gunicorn workers, or both?

Comment: CPUs / memory likely, as Gunicorn is linked to the Webserver only, so it's only the scheduler and executor processes that are blocking the resources for Gunicorn and the webserver